# Facing error while implementing data tables - TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datatables

I am trying to implement data-table into my view but it is showing the following error, I have tried all the ways to resolve the issue but I am not able to

Error:

```
base.js:1 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 't'
|     property '$parent' -> object with constructor 'i'
--- property '$$childTail' closes the circle
```

And this is my js code:

```
 self.initTable = function () {

        self.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withOption('ajax', function (data, callback) {
                
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    rowsData.push({
                        "Col1": `<div  style=" padding: 10px 0px;">XYZ</div>`,
                        "Col2": `<div  style=" padding: 10px 0px;">XYZ</div>`,
                        "Col3": `<div style=" padding: 10px 0px;">XYZ</div>`,
                    });
                   
                }
                callback({
                    recordsTotal: 10,
                    recordsFiltered: 10,
                    data: rowsData
                });
            })
            .withOption('createdRow', function (row) {
                angular.element(row).addClass('height-42');
                angular.element(row).addClass('hover-pointer');
            })
            .withDataProp('data')
            .withOption('serverSide', true)
            .withOption('processing', true)
            .withOption('deferLoading', true)
            .withOption('order', [])
            .withPaginationType('simple')
            .withDOM('tri')
            .withOption('pageLength', 10)
            .withLanguage({
                "sProcessing": "Loading"
            })
            .withOption('autoWidth', false);

        self.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Col1').withTitle('Col1').notSortable(),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Col2').withTitle('Col2').notSortable(),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Col3').withTitle('Col3').notSortable(),
            
        ];
        self.dtInstanceCallback = dtInstanceCallback;

        function dtInstanceCallback(instance) {
            self.dtInstance = instance;

        }
    }
```

Here I am trying to insert data in the rowsData array and then display that in the data table, but it is showing "no matching records found". Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong and why this issue is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is occurring because you have linked properly the values which you are using in the rowsData array. Update the title of the table columns with the correct heading and it will resolve the issue.